# Dynamically loading js script from bookmarklet

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load a script so I can use scripts on the page that is spawned by the bookmarklet. (view src: XHR followed by beautify.js followed by prettify.js)

I know what I am basically supposed to do ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106425/load-external-js-from-bookmarklet)) but what's happening is I can't find a good way to detect when the functions I need are actually loaded.

```
var doWhenLoaded = function (name) {
    if (typeof(eval(name)) === 'function') {
        eval(name+'()');
    } else {
        setTimeout( 
            function () {
                console.log("from timeout: "+new Date().getTime());
                doWhenLoaded(name,call); 
            } , 50 
        );
    }
}
```

I tried that but `eval(name+'()');` throws an error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718303/javascript-to-detect-when-external-javascripts-are-loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can force the scripts to get loaded synchronously before I end up calling them  by simply writing the document rather than setting them into the dom.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question, but to test if a function is available use:

```
var doWhenLoaded = function (name) {   
    if (typeof window[name] == 'function') {
      window[name]();
    } else {
      // set the timeout. Should have a limit, else it wil go on forever.
    }
    ...
};
```

#### Edit

Updated to use `window[name]`, but really should use a reference to the global object. But I guess it's ok to use window for a browser specific script.

The code above should not throw any errors. Since *name* is in the formal parameters, it's essentially a declared local variable. If *name* is undefined, then `typeof name` will return the string "undefined", which fails the test so `name()` is not evaluated.

Comment: Okay. I can't get this to work. Any time I call doWhenLoaded, if name is undefined I get an error! I also cannot get Chrome to give me a line number for the error. :(

Comment: Is what I'm trying to do simply impossible? I'm loading scripts in the new window made by the bookmarklet. How to run my test-check function in that window's "context"?